# html code to make Blackberry sing ring or vibrate

Tags: html, api, blackberry

I know that Blackberry has added new API's on OS5-6 that allow HTML5 code to access native features & widgets. Is it possible to make blackberry beep, ring, vibrate or sing (play mp3) to alert user of an event through an HTML page.

There is a java class called net.rim.device.api.system.Alert that might be accessible, but I don't know how to reach it with html/js.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an app with embedded browser wrapped in native shell? Then you can access almost all native features (the one which are exposed) using javascript extensions.

If it's purely a web app or webworks application, you should be able to find all native features that can be accessed from the browser at

[BlackBerry® WebWorks™ API Reference](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/webworks/api/index.html)

You still will be using [Javascript Extensions.](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/20770/Using_JS_extensions_in_your_widget_1324243_11.jsp)